# How to get actuall stack base from /proc/[pid]/maps?

Tags: linux

I'm trying to calculate offset from stack start to current stack pointer.

When I read /proc/[pid]/maps I see

```
  befdf000-bf000000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
```

0xbefdf000 looks like stack start address.
The problem is that when I look at SP register in gdb actual stack pointer is something like 0xbefff440.

Stack grows from high addresses to lower, but 0xbefff440 is > than 0xbefdf000, how it's possible that actual stack pointer is higher than highest stack address from /proc/*/maps ?

According to gdb memory examine function highest readable stack address is 0xbeffffff and this looks like real stack start, but what is befdf000 in proc maps? If it's isn't real stack base then how to get 0xbeffffff (which may change is ASLR enabled) from /proc/ ?

I'm running tests on ARM Debian in qemu. I disabled ASLR so stack address doesn't change between different program runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get what you're asking. Presumably your math is just wrong. 0xbefff440 is in the range 0xbefdf000 to 0xbeffffff, near the top of the range as expected.

Comment: But isn't range befdf000-bf000000 according to /proc/*/maps ? 0xbefff440 is not in range befdf000-bf000000 and that confuses me

Comment: Um, yes it is. 0xbf000000 is the address immediately after 0xbeffffff, and 0xbefff440 is jut a little ways below that. The ranges are expressed as half-open intervals, so `0xbefdf000-0xbeffffff` means all addresses x with `0xbefdf000 <= x < 0xbeffffff`, but since the address in question isn't right at the boundary that doesn't matter anyway.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I was inattentive and thought that first address is higher, I haven't noticed that second address is b**F**000000 I thought it's b**E**000000

Answer (score 0):

The two addresses are the two boundaries where stack can be. If an attempt to do stack operations would make it extend beyond one limit (in our case the lower or start address) the OS will attempt to increase the stack segment, lowering the low edge to make room for new stack entries, or may send a SEGV signal in case it fails to extend the stack (for example, if it would overlap with the program break AKA heap)

The first push writes to the last bytes of the segment.